# How to convert an wav file to mp3 file in windows phone?(Details Inside)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've searched for 2 days and I'm not getting how to convert the recorded wav file to an mp3 file; seen many questions even on stack overflow itself but no one gave the solution.

We can't execute System.Diagnostics.Process in Windows Phone.

there are many encoders like Lame, NAudio and so on; but don't know how to use that. .

recently I found example in codeproject named "mp3 Compressor", I tried use those classes but now i'm getting the below error,

[image]

Somebody please tell me how to achieve it. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to do that?
I'm afraid you can't and mustn't do that. at least with tools like those ones you mention. Note, for example, that Zune transform a media before transfering it to the devices.
As an idea, you could upload your file to a service online and make the conversion there. It's more difficult of course and providing you have a host you can use.

Comment: I've been working on the recorder sample in the msdn, it produces the wav format only, but the drawback in wav format is we can't add any ID tags in it I think, that's why i'm looking for the mp3 format. . .